# Avoid back button from refreshing a page on IE/Chrome browser

Tags: html, internet-explorer, jquery

I have developed a webpage which has an option to "Add link". On clicking the button, the user gets a pop up window to add a link. Once he submits the entry the base page refreshes to show up as a hyperlink and not "Add link" anymore. When the user clicks on the link, he gets redirected to the webpage belonging to the link. On clicking the back button on IE/chrome from the webpage corresponding to the link he comes back to the initial page but with an option of "Add link" again. Which is incorrect, he should just see the link and not an option to add link. However on refreshing the page it goes back to show the link. Noticing this issue only on IE and google chrome and works well with Mozilla Firefox. Kindly help.

Comment: Are you storing this "Add link" event in a session or cookie?  From what I can tell (assuming code) is that you want to be using Ajax to update this "Add link" state.

Comment: "However on refreshing the page it goes back to show the link." - is that behavior correct? Do you want to see the actual link, and not the Add a Link when the Back button is clicked? What should you see if that page was bookmarked?

Comment: Code or repro URL is needed.